# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ,String Array

Tags: java, android, arrays

How to Fix the error Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0 :

I try to simplify the code and for example the Boolean I is some times true or false, it dose not matter they work fine.
what i cannot find out is how to declare the array aList from bListA like this part of code : `aList[y]=bListA[x]`
`

class B:

```
public String[] bList ={"a","b","c"};
```

class A:

```
String[] bListA=new B().bList;
int x;
int y = 0;
String[] aList= new String[0];
boolean I;
for (x=0;x<bListA.length;x++){
    if(I){
        aList[y]=bListA[x];
        y++;
    }
}
```

> the error that is shown to me is :   Caused by:
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
>   When you Click on it ,android studio take you to the line:  `aList[y]=bListA[x]`

How To Fix an error like this? notice that i do not want to use a try and catch, because if every time I is true then i get an error and i have to show the massage that sorry! but i get the error forever! only if you think that the error is going to show up one time it will be a good idea.

Comment: String[] aList= new String[bListA.length()];

Comment: your aList size is 0 only.

Comment: i know all of that my friends , this is not the answare ,
 
String[] aList= new String[bListA.length()] i want aList to have its own size because i want to use it for a list view , 
 
your aList size is 0 only. yes and i want to expend that size every time a new I is found if not it should be zero.

Comment: You mentioned in a comment below ZAhmeds answer, that you want to save the elements if `I` is true. Since you declare `I` directly before the `for-loop` and never change it, the length of `aList` will either be 0 `(I = false)` or always the same length as `bList (I = true)`. You should explain what you are using `I` for, I think your problem would be more understandable then.

Comment: You cannot expend an array, you can only assign a new, larger container to the same variable. This code only creates a container that can store nothing (because its size is 0) hence everything that you try to put into it is immediately out of bounds. As said by others, look into `ArrayList`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to reverse your bList.

Here you have declared aList with size 0 so you wont be able to add any elements to it

```
String[] aList= new String[0];
```

Hence anything with aList[1] etc will give you error.

so if you want to reverse, do

```
String[] aList= new String[bListA.length()];
```

and then in for loop you can do `aList[y]=bListA[x]`

Also if you want a dynamic array use

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(bListA[x]);
```

This way you can add as many as you want

Comment: i want aList to have its own size

Comment: List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(bListA[x]); this might do it i check it out and comming back a few minutes

Answer (score 2):

You declared an array with a size equals to zero.

```
String[] aList = new String[0];
```

This is why you have this exception.

You should do this instead:

```
String[] aList = new String[bListA.length()];
```

Comment: i want a list to have its own size.

Comment: As mention by @kapsym, use ArrayList instead of Array.